# How to simulate sip protocol to call a voip phone

Tags: sip, voip

I have a question about SIP which is used in VoIP
I want to simulate SIP protocol (in widows or Ubuntu ) and call a VoIP phone by computer and transmitting my desired data which is coded by G.729 codec through the connection. As matter of fact I need hint  which can help me how to simulate a SIP for me (inviting, 200Ok, Ack and so on)

Could you please help me
thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is not the place to ask which software is best for doing something. It’s about programming. Have you tried to code such a piece of software?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that I need hint for writing the code which execute my purpose

Comment: Which programming language have you chosen?

Comment: I prefer to work with C or Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the [SIP SIMPLE Python library](http://sipsimpleclient.org/projects/sipsimpleclient/wiki/SipDeveloperGuide).

Here is a [minimalist working example](https://github.com/amakukha/sipsimpleclient-example) for establishing a SIP call in Python.

Otherwise you can send simple SIP requests over TCP or UDP, but there is a risk that you'll have to implement a lot of logic even before you can authenticate to your proxy.

Comment: Thank you so much Andriy Makukha